# Need help in an Apttus Issue

Tags: managed-package

We are using Apttus in our salesforce org for CPQ(Configure Price Quote). There we have two objects **'Proposal'** and **'Proposal Line Item'(Child of Proposal object)**. In the **'Proposal object'** there are few fields which shows in UI as the form of button. Upon clicking them an excel file connects with APTTUS and displays the **'Proposal Line Item records"** as shown below.

[image]

**Below is the snip of the excel which opens on clicking button.**

[image]

**Below is the snip of the button field.**
[image]

Now I have to create two new fields in the **'Proposal Line Item'** object and add those fields to the excel file also which generates upon clicking of the button.

Please help me in knowing how can I update the excel sheet to include new fields ? And where exactly is this excel file stored ?

Thanks!
Ruchi

Answer (score 1):

This hyperlink is opening a VF page that likely has some actions occurring in the controller of the page.  Unless this is something you had custom built by Apttus PS team, then you likely don't have access to the controller as it will be part of the managed package.  If it is something that was custom built and you do have access to it, then you would want to start in the controller of that page.

I warn you though, that is pretty dangerous if you are not familiar with the code.  So proceed at your own risk.

My advice would be to contact Apttus and see if you can get a Professional Services engagement to have them look into this unless you are extremely familiar with the code, but since you are asking on here, I am guessing that is not the case.

Comment: Hi Chris, I had checked all the vf pages and no where I found the vf page similar to the hyperlink name. Can it might be a case that it is something built by apttus which we might not have access to ?